# Convert a block of strings to a block in Red

Tags: red

How to convert a block of strings into a block?

To change this:

```
keep rejoin['circle " " coord " " 5 " "]]]

["circle 10x10 5 " "circle 20x20 5 " "circle 30x30 5 "]
```

to this:

```
[circle 10x10 5 circle 20x20 5 circle 30x30 5]
```

I want to change it so it can be used with VID.

```
view [
      size 800x600
      base 780x580
      draw drawblock
     ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To convert `string!` to Red code, you need to LOAD it:

`red>> load "circle 10x10 5 "
== [circle 10x10 5]`

So for block of `string!`s, just load them in loop:

`collect [
    foreach arg ["circle 10x10 5 " "circle 20x20 5 " "circle 30x30 5 "] [
        keep load arg
    ]
]
== [circle 10x10 5 circle 20x20 5 circle 30x30 5]`

However, for code generation, it is better to use Red types directly and not start with strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `load rejoin` to convert `["set " "of " "spaced " "strings"]`
to

```
red>> load rejoin ["circle 10x10 5 " "circle 20x20 5 " "circle 30x30 5 "]
== [circle 10x10 5 circle 20x20 5 circle 30x30 5]
```

Best thing to do is not have a block of strings in the first place and try to use literals and code as much as possible.

#### Edit:

For your particular use case this would work:

```
drawblock: collect [
    foreach arg [10 20 30] [
        keep compose [circle (as-pair arg arg) 5]
    ]
]
```

*p.s.* if you are playing around with view [this gist](https://gist.github.com/DideC/85d60c99f97f2e4972a6f7b09a1fe630) could help